# Start external .exe when start debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I've a print emulator that would like to **automatic** start/kill whenever starting/stop debug my app.

I thought about build events but I dont think it is the best place to put it on.

There is a good place to put this commands?

Comment: Why not just start it when the app starts and kill it right before it exits? Maybe something like this `public static void Main() { #if DEBUG Process.Start(somePath); #endif }`?

Comment: Oh, it seems to be a good idea. Just thinking out of box. How I don't think about it before... Tks @AhmedAbdelhameed!

Answer (score 1):

If you go into your Project's Debug settings, under "Start action", there is an option that allows you to specify an external program via path.

Comment: Hi @user10574815, Tks for reply. It's not what I want. If I do it my application will not start.